# What is XHCI ACPI?

Tags: suspend, thinkpad, acpi

I've been having a bear of a time getting this new Lenovo Thikpad X1 Carbon Gen 9 to suspend. I think these are the lines that indicate the cause of my problem

```
systemd-sleep[682835]: System returned from sleep state.
bluetoothd[829]: Controller resume with wake event 0x1
kernel: usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

After seeing this I wanted to disable XHCI ACPI, because I've seen this suggested on the forums. I did this,

```
❯ acpitool -e | grep XHCI
7. XHCI  S3 *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0ed  pci:0000:00:14.0
```

And then I disabled `7` with `sudo acpitool -W7`. Now it shows `*disabled` and my laptop suspends. What does XHCI ACPI wake do? Is this needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Host_Controller_Interface), the extensible host controller interface, is a specification for USB host controllers. It allows a generic XHCI driver to control any XHCI-compliant USB host controller.

XHCI wake allows USB-connected devices to wake your system up from suspend. You only need it if you want that ability. You can find which USB device woke up your machine by paying attention to the line,

```
kernel: usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 120 using xhci_hcd
```

The `usb 3-3` is in reference to the bus (first number) and device number (second number). You can see what device resides there with, `lsusb -s 3:3` in this case you got back,

> Bus 003 Device 003: ID 174f:2454 Syntek Integrated Camera

Which tells you the USB webcam (integrated), a Syntek Integrated Camera, is waking up your machine. Because it's a Thinkpad

Comment: Follow up: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702639/3285