# Can I disable one XHCI device from being able to ACPI wakeup the machine?

Tags: suspend, acpi

Rather than disabling all XHCI ACPI wakeup calls. Is it possible to disable just wakeup calls from one device. Say my integrated, Syntek Integrated Camera, on bus 3 sub device 3. Can I disable just *that* device from waking up my machine?

---

This is a follow up to [*"What is XHCI ACPI?"*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/702633/3285)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be simpler to use the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/.../remove` to "unplug" the problematic USB device on suspend, and then have it auto-hotplug again on resume?

Or if that doesn't work, maybe you could use `/sys/bus/usb/devices/.../authorized` to set the problem device as "unauthorized" on suspend, and back to "authorized" on resume?